# orchard cms - how to custom tags route

Tags: orchardcms

I added some tags to the content, so the URL of tag is: http://tuyensinh247.thangs2.net/Tags/h%E1%BB%93%20ch%C3%AD%20minh

I want to replace it like:
http://tuyensinh247.thangs2.net/Tags/ho-chi-minh

How can I do it, and where do I start with code on Tag Module.

Many thanks from your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write the tags with standard characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9 instead of using characters of your mother language (i have decoded your URL and it returns hồ chí minh instead of ho-chi-minh).